# Driver manager not using the correct driver for the DB url

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, amazon-aurora, treasure-data

I have a java application which is able create a connection to multiple DB.

We are loading these drivers:

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
Class.forName("com.treasure_data.jdbc.TreasureDataDriver");
```

When I try to connect to aurora DB I would expect `DriverManager` to use the MariaDB driver - but instead it is using treasure_data driver.

```
java.sql.Connection conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:aurora://YYY-aurora.XXXXX.com:3306/SomeDBName", "USER", "PASSWORD");
```

and this is the error I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql:aurora://YYY-aurora.XXXXX.com:3306/SomeDBName. URL prefix must be jdbc:td://
```

Why is `DriverManager` using the treasure_data Driver?

Comment: what you mean by expect? you have to specify the database cases and its parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.sql.DriverManager` will ask **each** registered driver to create a connection with the JDBC url until one driver either returns a (non-null) `java.sql.Connection` or throws an `SQLException`.

From JDBC 4.2 section 9.2 *The Driver interface*:

> When the `DriverManager` is trying to establish a connection, it calls that driver's `connect` method and passes the driver the URL. If the `Driver` implementation understands the URL, it will return a `Connection` object or throw a `SQLException` if a connection cannot be maded to the database. If the `Driver` implementation does not understand the URL, it will return `null`.

From the [`Driver.connect` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#connect-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-):

> Attempts to make a database connection to the given URL. The driver should return "null" if it realizes it is the wrong kind of driver to connect to the given URL. This will be common, as when the JDBC driver manager is asked to connect to a given URL it passes the URL to each loaded driver in turn.
>
> The driver should throw an `SQLException` if it is the right driver to connect to the given URL but has trouble connecting to the database.

So a compliant JDBC driver **must** return `null` when it is asked to create connection for a JDBC URL it doesn't recognize/support. Only when the URL is supported (eg because the prefix matches the driver), is a driver allowed to throw an `SQLException` (eg when there is a syntax error in the rest of the JDBC URL, or if the connection cannot be established).

So the `com.treasure_data.jdbc.TreasureDataDriver` is misbehaving because it throws an `SQLException` for an URL it doesn't recognise; you need to file a bug report with the author of that driver.